# Error reporting issue in Laravel project for login as well as in other pages

Tags: laravel-5, error-reporting

Fatal error: Uncaught ErrorException: Undefined variable: e in /var/www/html/project/app/Exceptions/Handler.php:51 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/project/app/Exceptions/Handler.php(51): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Undefined varia...', '/var/www/html/s...', 51, Array) #1 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(112): App\Exceptions\Handler->render(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(ErrorException)) #2 /var/www/html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(89): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->renderHttpResponse(Object(ErrorException)) #3 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleException(Object(ErrorException)) #4 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/project/app/Exceptions/Handler.php on line 51

getting this error if I submit the login page with wrong username and password.
This is even showing when I do ini_set('display_errors',true); otherwise just blank page

I have given write permission for storage folder as well as debug mode is true.

Error messages are not properly showing in any places.

Please help

Comment: nobody to help me?

Comment: Did you find something? I'm having a similar problem right now...